# Xcode 4 and controllers with xibs

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, cocoa-design-patterns

I have main xib with a splitview controller and ive dragged the ibactions and properties on to the AppDelegate code.

So in my applicationDidFinishLaunching i would like to load a controller which uses a xib into one of the nsviews that i have linked up.

The problem is that i can't use xcode to link ibactions and properties from the new xib into the controller that is going to load it.

Does that have to be done programatically?

Comment: i've now managed to set the files owner to be an NSViewController and draggged that to the customview and set the action to view.

does that mean that i can now have an outlet called 'view' in the filesowner controller.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me, but you should take a look at split view template and some examples at Apple Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of exactly what you are trying to do. However, it sounds like the 'splitview controller' you are referring to should be a subclass of `NSViewController`, then it can manage the xib for you.

Again, I'm not certain what you are trying to do; perhaps post a snippet of code?

Comment: i have a mainwindow with a splitviewcontroller which has two outlets set, one called bookmarks and the other called pageView.

i now want to add a xib into that view with another controller to control it.